# Header "snapping back" from scrolling

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this problem where my header is to broad when I'm at the top of the page, after scrolling the height adjusts to the desired level.

Top
[image: Top of the page]
Scrolling
[image: After Scrolling]

This all leads back to a class being added:

```
<body class="[...] fixed-header-scroll">
```

Thing is, I didnt set up the page and can't figure out how exactly these classes are set.

I'm running a Child of "The Story" on Wordpress and traced the whole thing back to

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

But from this point I'm really not good enough wird Wordpress and googling didn't help either...

Thanks in Advance!

P.S. [The Page](http://lallaundvilasyoga.de/)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a standard feature of most themes now a days. On scrolling down it compresses the header, so it doesn't occupy much space. If you want to completely remove this functionality then you will have to search for "fixed-header-scroll" in your js file. It should look something like this.
jQuery('body').addClass('fixed-header-scroll'). just comment it out. You will then have to style the bar to your liking.

If you just want to make the bar look similar to the one when you scroll, you will have to make the below changes. But there still will be a slight jerk when the class is added.

```
On line 1079 of style.css replace padding-bottom to 
  padding-bottom: 9px;

and on line 77 of style.css replace margin-top with to
  margin-top: 3px !important;
```

**EDIT:**
Another way would be to add the class to the body tag manually but it will be automatically overridden by js. So i would suggest to go into js/main.js and search for "STICKY HEADER". You will see a block of text so just comment it out, (from stickey header to resizeable image gallery). Now goto header.php and in the body tag you will see the body_class() function with some css classes in it. So just add 'fixed-header-scroll' like other classes.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the class instead of fixing the .css?